# Carousel control help needed

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, winrt-xaml

By referring 
http://silverlightcarousel.codeplex.com/

I have created 3D carousel control with dynamic items in c# xaml.  But up to 7 or 10 items it will be ok for displaying. but when there are more than 10 items ;it appears to be more congested to see.

I want to display maximum of 5 or 3 items at a time even there are more than 3 or 5 items in the list.

What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in the code there are some constant values being assigned to create the icons that are being displayed on the canvas.

```
private const double DEFAULT_SCALE = 0.5;
private const double MINIMUM_SCALE = 0;
private const double MAXIMUM_SCALE = 1;
private double _scale = DEFAULT_SCALE;
```

If you change the values for the scaling values you will be able to have the items further away from selection (i.e. at the far end of the carousel), become smaller than they are currently set to. This should create the illusion of further distance, but more importantly allow you to bind a larger list of items to the carousel.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new list with only the items you want to display in the carrousel.

Comment: You can create a condition where you new list will have max 5 items

Comment: thank you for your help.  I got a coverflow control instead of carousel control.it will be satisfy my requirement except it will not move to first item after last item. i got that from [link](http://silverlightcoverflow.codeplex.com/)